Android Push Notifications: Icon not displaying in notification, white square shown instead in specific devices
I have created an application with Flutter. When we receiving notification from firebase campaign messaging It's not showing the app icon but when we are receiving from api it's working fine no problem at all. The problem is identified on motorola phone as of now.
I'm attaching My code here Please help If you know or ever fixed this problem

void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  CacheHelper.init();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

 
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    null, //Icon
    [
      //! initializing notification

      NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: '1',
        channelName: 'example',
        channelDescription: 'notification',
        ledColor: Colors.green,
        playSound: true,
        enableVibration: true,
        enableLights: true,
      ),
      NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: "0",
        channelName: ‘example’,
        channelDescription: 'notification',
        channelGroupKey: 'notification_group',
        ledColor: Colors.green,
        playSound: true,
        enableVibration: true,
        // locked: true,
        enableLights: true,
        importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
      ),
    ],
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async {
    notificationProvider.fetchNotification();
    if (message.data['action'] == true) {
      await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
          content: NotificationContent(
            id: 99,
            channelKey: "0",
            title: message.data['title'],
            body: message.data['body'],
            payload: {
              'data': jsonEncode(message.data),
            },
          ),
          actionButtons: [
            NotificationActionButton(
                key: "y", label: "Yes", actionType: ActionType.SilentAction),
            NotificationActionButton(
                key: "n", label: "No", actionType: ActionType.SilentAction),
          ]);
    } else {
      await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
          content: NotificationContent(
              id: int.parse(message.data['notification_id']),
              channelKey: "0",
              roundedBigPicture: true,
              title: message.data['title'],
              hideLargeIconOnExpand: true,
              displayOnBackground: true,
              backgroundColor: darkgreen,
              customSound: message.data['sound'],
              payload: {
                'data': jsonEncode(message.data),
              },
              // locked: true,
              body: message.data['body'],
              bigPicture: message.data['image'],
              notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
              criticalAlert: true,
              category: NotificationCategory.Recommendation,
              autoDismissible: true));
    }
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  // getFCMToken().then((value) {
  //   log('FCM token : ${value}');
  //   token = value!;
  //   loginProvider.setFirebase_token(value);
  // });

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ProfileDataProvider>.value(
          value: profileDataProvider),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<NotificationProvider>.value(
          value: notificationProvider),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginProvider>.value(value: loginProvider),
     
    ], child: MyApp()),
  );



//! for background app notification
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // log(Notification_Data: ${jsonEncode(message.data)}");
  if (message.data['action'] == true) {
    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
          id: 99,
          channelKey: "0",
          title: message.data['title'],
          body: message.data['body'],
          payload: {
            'data': jsonEncode(message.data),
          },
        ),
        actionButtons: [
          NotificationActionButton(
              key: "y", label: "Yes", actionType: ActionType.SilentAction),
          NotificationActionButton(
              key: "n", label: "No", actionType: ActionType.SilentAction),
        ]);
  } else {
    await AwesomeNotifications()
        .createNotification(
            content: NotificationContent(
      groupKey: 'notification_group',
      id: int.parse(message.data['notification_id']),
      channelKey: '0',
      roundedBigPicture: true,
      title: message.data['title'],
      // locked: true,
      hideLargeIconOnExpand: true,
      displayOnBackground: true,
      backgroundColor: darkgreen,
      customSound: message.data['sound'],
      autoDismissible: true,
      payload: {
        'data': jsonEncode(message.data),
      },
      body: message.data['body'],
      bigPicture: message.data['image'],
      notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
      criticalAlert: true,
      category: NotificationCategory.Message,
      actionType: ActionType.Default,
    ))
        .then((value) {
      // log(Created Notificaction $value");
    }).catchError((e) {
      log(e.toString());
    });
  }
}

[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/7CvzlpeK.jpg)

I want to know the cause of this issue and as It's not happening all the devices so I don't know where to start. I'm also sharing my gradle setting
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
    }
}


def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw  GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '4.1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    packagingOptions {
            pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 34
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.farm.android"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 54
        // versionCode 7 old  
        // targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        // versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    signingConfigs {
        release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
       
}

My manifest setting
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.farmdss.android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
        <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
   <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:label=“Farm"
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
        
                    
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <intent-filter>
            
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data
        android:host="farm.page.link"
        android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
  android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>


        <intent-filter>
       
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.EnableImpeller"
    android:value="true" />
   <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
              <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="pushnotificationapp"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
            <!-- <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" /> -->
    </application>
</manifest>


Try to use android asset studio generated icon for notification icon in your code with drawable folder.
